# BBC News Sentence: Isn't it an indirect speech? If yes, where is 'that'?

Tags: reported-speech

I have often come across sentences of an indirect speech that do not contain 'that'. As a standard rule taught in schools here, we include 'that' when we turn a direct speech sentence into indirect.

> He said, "I'm coming"

should be...

> He said ***that*** he is coming.

But on [the BBC](http://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-30664604), I found this sentence:

> *Search and rescue agency chief Bambang Soelistyo **said** an underwater vehicle was being lowered to take pictures.*

On the same page:

> *He **said** the larger of the objects was 10 metres by five (32ft by 16ft) but that strong currents made operating the underwater vehicle difficult.*

**BUT**

> *Mr Soelistyo **said on Saturday that** the large objects had been detected by sonar from an Indonesian navy ship.*

Comment: I think we include 'that' only if the statement is 'exclusively' spoken by a person. In those examples, those are their opinions? Maybe? I'm not sure! +1 for this question though!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Omitting *that* in this sort of context is quite ordinary, and acceptable in all registers.

In these sentences *that* acts as a *subordinator* (some grammarians call it a *complementizer*): it tells the reader or hearer that the following *content clause* (a clause headed by a finite verb) is subordinate to the head clause.

Subordinator *that* may be omitted in many circumstances. The 'rules' are fairly complicated (they are detailed in *CGEL*, Ch. 11, §3.1), but the one which is operative here is that *that* may be omitted when “**the content clause is complement to a common and quite general verb of cognition or communication**” (CGEL, 953). The *that* clauses in your examples are all complements of the verb *SAY*, and *SAY* is exactly that kind of verb.

Note, by the way, that in your last example the *that* is required as a pragmatic matter: without the *that* it is unclear whether *on Saturday* modifies the head clause (Mr S said it on Saturday) or the subordinate clause (large objects were detected on Saturday).

Comment: Note: CGEL = [The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Cambridge_Grammar_of_the_English_Language)

Answer (score -1):

You're right, technically, but colloquially the *that* has come to be somewhat optional where its absence does not introduce an ambiguity.

Also, holding up the BBC News website as an example of "proper English" is not a good idea; I find spelling mistakes and grammatical errors on it daily.

Comment: You just rose great doubts in my mind about the credibility of the BBC! Not sure, how to respond! :( Natives already indirectly advised me to stop referring Indian Newspapers and other lit and now you (probably native!) coming up with this! Phew! No source to learn the language for a non-native like me now....

Comment: @MaulikV: Try the Independent or the Guardian. Much more reliable. Of course, I don't know whether they will be to your tastes politically!

Comment: The Guardian is so infamous for typographical errors that it has the nickname 'The Grauniad'.  Anything that's published on a tight schedule is prone to errors.  I don't think the BBC news is really that much worse than anywhere else.